# change icon on collapse in Bootstrap 2.3 not in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **bootstrap 2.3** **collapse** in my project. I need to change icons on collapse means on show and hide I need to change icons. with bootstrap 3 some shown and hidden functions are showing in internet but I need with Bootstrap 2.3. Please let me know how to fix this.

[image]

```css
.arrow-down{
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAYAAABWdVznAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAAHwAAAB8ARUP7eQAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuNWWFMmUAAACISURBVChTvc+xCoNAEIThDXkQH8FCYhGwsRLEgJ2lEN81VQg2toIW2qVK7z9RREEtHfjg7liWOTslIZzxeJhgYhU+uOmykwQd3rpEaNEg1cMiFzyh4Rc82BU5fqjxf5xS4AstUwMtmJNBm0r4eKCHhtViMzFUTzSsGkd/W9XbrLGXO9zxeG7MBoKmGaM1wCzfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat right;
}

.arrow-up{
    width: 16px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAMCAYAAABr5z2BAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAbrQAAG60BIeRSlQAAABh0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMC41ZYUyZQAAANpJREFUOE9jGJzAwsJCyM7OztPMzIwPKkQ8sLe353F2dl7v6ur6BEjPBmI1qBRxAGgAh6OjY4m7u/t/oCF/gQacBtJuUGmiAQvQC7YuLi5fgZr/Ozk5fQCyC6ByxANLS0sxoAsuAzX/dXNz+w9kzwKGDydUmijADPSSA9AVv4CG/Ae5CIhjoXL4gY2NjSjQxlKghtdQb5wGGhYClcYPgBotgQG5BqjxN9TpM4CaNaDS+AEoDQA13ABpBNr+G2hQkpWVFS9UmijABDTAEGj7DqAhIFuZIMLYAAMDAPuUQ9EUeG3QAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat right;
}

.accordion-heading .accordion-toggle{
    width:88%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle arrow-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <p> first table</p>
        <p>First Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle arrow-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
         <p> second table</p>
        <p>second Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well I can see bootstrap's javascript is adding "in collapse" classes to the active accordion content. I think you'd have to extend that javascript and add a class to those .accordion-toggle tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated. Yes - the first pure CSS solution was not satisfactory. If you dare to add some javascript, you can do this :

```js
$('.accordion-group').on('show', function() {
    $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
});    
$('.accordion-group').on('hide', function() {
    $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
});
```

It is using the bootstrap collapse `hide` / `show` events directly on the collapse sections. Still without `width` / `height`, but otherwise similar to the markup in OP.

new demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4m1u2rb4/**

Comment: I saw your fiddle. In that we have problem with class ".collapsed". this class is adding dynamical when we are showing the hiding part. But first time the collapsed is not there.

Comment: @Rayudu, yes and the logic is quickly messed up when you close a section, sry for that. Have updated the answer, hope you find it better (seems to work)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html >
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<style class="cp-pen-styles">.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: left;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
</div> <!-- end container -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body></html>
```